# Python pandas two data frames

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames one with ages for 15 people for 50 years i.e. 15 rows x 51 columns. Another with two columns age and a variable d. I want a third data frame that gives me value of d for each age in the first data frame i.e. it will have 15 rows and 51 columns just like the first df. How should i go about this?

Comment: Please can you update a sample of your input data, the code you have try so far and the expected output? Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. You may find the site [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) section and this [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) checklist useful guidance for asking a good question. It is easier for people to help you if you include the code that you've worked on to solve the problem and ideally provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

Mini example of your data:

```
data = {'person': ['a','b','c'],'age1':[10,11,12],'age2':[11,12,13]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
data = {'var_d': ['a1','a2','a3','a4','a5'],'age':[10,11,12,13,14]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image: dataframes example:]

Lets create dictionary from df2, convert var_d value into age value:

```
age_to_var_dict = dict(zip(df2.age, df2.var_d))
```

[image: age_to_var_d dictionary]

Now let's iterate over df1 age values and convert them into var_d values:

```
df3 = df1.copy(deep=True)
def convert_age_to_var_d(col):
    result = []
    for i,val in enumerate(col):
        result.append(age_to_var_dict[val])
    return result
df3.iloc[:,1:] = df1.iloc[:,1:].apply(convert_age_to_var_d)
# rename age columns to var_d
df3.columns = ['person','var_d1','var_d2']
```

We got df3 with persons var_d for each age:
[image: df3 with var_d values for each age column]

Comment: Hope I understood you correctly, next time please try to insert a sample of your input data, the code you have tried so far, and the expected output as people already ask you in the comments.

Comment: Hi I ran this code, I have numerical values in place of a1,a2,... So it runs fine but all the values show up as 0. So if I have a value 0.000934 it shows up as 0. How do I fix this?

Comment: I edited the solution, now it also fits the case you mentioned.
The cause of the problem was the dtype of the columns of the table. So I created a new list and returned it instead of editing the column values themselves.